# how to call function in module from block_view

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I am writing a Drupal 7 module that queries my db and prints out a view_block with a list of projects belonging to the current logged user:

```
ID ClientName ProjectName ProjectDescription
 1     mickey       toon1        bla bla bla
 2      mouse       toon2        bla bla bla
```

At this point, I need the user to select one of his projects to proceed to visualization.

EDIT:

**what I need to do is to call another function in my module and pass it the ID for the project selected by the current user.**

I know how to add a link to every row in the table and bring the ID value with me to the next page, using GET['id'] to retrieve it, but I really don't want to change the url for security reasons - namely, I don't want users to change the ID in the url and see other people's projects, nor prevent it to happen. I prefer to keep url clean as much as possible.

What is in Drupal 7 the right logic to allow the user select one project and then call another function in my module to load data according to the selected ID?

Comment: it's a custom block ?

Comment: Yes it is a block view made by my module

Comment: if you want to keep url , you need to use ajax to another custom url, and pass with POST your parameter and then on response replace table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would implement an [hook_menu](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7.x). With this solution you need to pass the Id of the project in the url, but an hook menu allow you to define 2 functions. The access function will check if the user has access to the project, the callback function will retrieve the project and show the project details.

This is a simple example of how I would implement it:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function my_module_menu() {
    $items['my_module/show_project_detail/%'] = array(
        'title' => 'Show Task Detail',
        'access callback' => 'show_project_access',
        'access arguments' => array(1),
        'title callback' => false,
        'page callback' => 'show_project',
        'page arguments' => array(1),
    );
    return $items;
}

function show_project_access( $sProjectId ){
    // checks if the user has access to $sProjectId.
    // returns true if he has access, otherwise returns false
}

function show_project( $sProjectId ){
    //returns the html of the task's detail view
}
```

Then to call the hook_menu you will call this url
https://my_drupal/my_module/show_project_detail/123
where 123 is the project Id.

Comment: I don’t want to be rude and downvote you but I explicitly stated I don’t want to change the url for security reasons

Comment: @user299791 This is a correct implementation. Access control is the key, no matter how the id param is transported. Id in url is not an issue at all. Furthermore, a user might want to copy or share such link to actually view the corresponding project later from another page or whatever.. How would you do without the id in url ? You can still implement a form that POSTs the id and redirects to the corresponding page but it would be a bit overkil and it won't resolve the access control. You can't navigate somewhere using an anchor link that does not fully describes its destination [URL].

Comment: it might be correct, but not what I asked. it's totally doable without id in url, POST is the right solution and it does solve the access control.

Comment: @EricLavault: thank you for have clearly expressed my point of view :)

Comment: @user299791 So sorry I was pretty sure you did ask _What is in Drupal 7 the **right logic** to allow the user..._. I just would like to know how do you prevent users to make POST requests with any random id params like they would do via GET ? What kind of magic can actually prevent users from accessing content just by changing the origin of a parameter ?